# Django extensions - dumpscript not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I have a simple Tag model and have already properly populated the database with some data. Django extensions are properly installed. However, when I try dumpscript, it complains the Tag model has no attribute "_collect_sub_objects", can anyone tell me what's going on? Is this a bug?

Here's models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

and this is the exact line of the dumpscript command:

```
python manage.py dumpscript tags.Tag > scripts/testdata_tag1.py
```

and the error message:

```
Processing model: Tag
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_extensions-0.7.1-py2.6.egg/django_extensions/management/commands/dumpscript.py", line 238, in skip
self.instance._collect_sub_objects(sub_objects)
AttributeError: 'Tag' object has no attribute '_collect_sub_objects'
```

My Django version is 1.3.1 and extensions version is 0.7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in django-extensions that introduced an incompatibility with 1.3+

You'll have to grab the latest version (`.8 alpha`) to make it work.

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions